# What type of statistical models would be useful for evaluating an athlete's performance?

Tags: experiment-design, optimal

Suppose a performance athlete wants to use statistics to design an optimal exercise regimen. The goal of the statistical model should be to essentially maximize the performance of the athlete by choosing the ideal set of exercises suitable for his/her body.

Basic Method

1. Identify key metrics targeting improvement (e.g. Speed, strength)
2. Identify an exercise plan (e.g. The usual kind, like with squats, bicep curls, etc).
3. Execute the exercise plan
4. Observe changes to the metrics

### Example

The simplest case would simply be trial and error.

1. Start with an exercise plan.
2. Observe after each session how well the individual performs (giving enough time for recovery).
3. If there is improvement, then it works. If not, then you're better off not doing the plan. This model essentially maps performance like a threshold whereby if enough metrics are improved sufficiently, then the model crosses the threshold should yield "Yes, do it" and if they don't, it yields "No, don't do it.'

**Limitations:**

But this approach seems way to simplistic and inefficient. It would be far better if there was a way to measure how particular exercises were affecting training so they could be compared and the best ones selected.

In someways this sounds like ordering the exercises from most useful to least useful and then putting the ones that are most useful into the plan.

### My Confusion

There are too many different kinds of variables present. I am confused where to begin in designing a model like this.

### My Question

Do models like this exist? If so, can someone provide me with an example and explain why it meets the goals I defined above?

If not, can someone offer a suggest as to what kind of statistical models/techniques I should explore in order to create a model like the above?

Comment: It seems like you're really talking about how to design an experiment to assess these different treatments. Would you say that's the case? The model that you would use would probably be clear once you've got the design specified.

Comment: There seems to be some published papers on this, so try to search. Some few:  https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.10.31.20223768v1.full,  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235626918_Effects_of_Two_Different_Training_Programs_with_Same_Workload_on_Throwing_Velocity_by_Experienced_Water_Polo_Players#pf6,